# NSManagedObjectContext Not saving properly to SQLite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

SO,

I have a problem with Core Data and trying to save data out to a SQLite database correctly.

I have two "Apps": one for loading the SQLite data (Lets call that "Loader.App"), and one for displaying the data ("Display.App"). The loader is just a convenience "bridge" between a web-based CMS which exports data as JSON data and the App which needs an SQLite DB (which is, again, loaded by Core Data).

When I save the context in Loader.App, it saves the data into the SQLite file. I can open this file in a SQLite reader (like Base.App) and it shows all the data. **The problem is: when I bring that SQLite file to Display.App, it copies the file into the documents directory but it doesn't have any data inside of it.** It does, however, have all of the proper tables - just like the SQLite file before I load the data.

The odd thing is that if **I open the SQLite DB file in a reader (Base.App) and VACUUM the database, it loads in Display.App perfectly fine**. From experience with file io in Python I know that if you don't close the file properly, the data isn't written to the file from the io buffer. Clearly, the data is being written to the SQLite file (thus I can open it with a reader (Base.App)). But it makes me wonder if there a file closing method that I am not calling?

Basically...

**Method 1:**

1. Run Loader.App
2. Copy MyAppDB.sqlite to Display.App
3. Run Display.App

**Result**: MyAppDB.sqlite has no data inside of it

**Method 2:**

1. Run Loader.App
2. Open MyAppDB.sqlite with reader (Base.App)
3. VACUUM
4. Copy MyAppDB.sqlite to Display.App
5. Run Display.App

**Result**: MyAppDB.sqlite contains data and we have much joy.

**Here is a trimmed down version of my Loader.App:**

```
    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {

        @autoreleasepool {
            // Create the managed object context
            NSManagedObjectContext *context = managedObjectContext();

            // Custom code here...
            importDataEntriesFromJSON(context);

            // Save the managed object context
            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![context save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Error while saving %@", ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    static NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel() {
        static NSManagedObjectModel *model = nil;
        if (model != nil) {
            return model;
        }

        NSString *path = @"MyAppDB";
        path = [path stringByDeletingPathExtension];
        NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"mom"]];
        model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

        return model;
    }


    static NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext() {
        static NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
        if (context != nil) {
            return context;
        }

        @autoreleasepool {
            context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];

            NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel()];
            [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

            NSString *STORE_TYPE = NSSQLiteStoreType;

            NSString *path = @"MyAppDB";
            path = [path stringByDeletingPathExtension];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"sqlite"]];

            // Clear old SQLite
            NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            NSError *error;
            [manager removeItemAtURL:url error:&error];

            //NSError *error;
            NSPersistentStore *newStore = [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:STORE_TYPE configuration:nil URL:url options:nil error:&error];

            if (newStore == nil) {
                NSLog(@"Store Configuration Failure %@", ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
            }
        }
        return context;
    }

    void importDataEntriesFromJSON( NSManagedObjectContext *context ) {
        NSError* err = nil;
        NSString* dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data_entries" ofType:@"json"];
        NSArray* data_entries = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath]
                                                        options:kNilOptions
                                                          error:&err];
        NSLog(@"Imported %lu data_entries from JSON", (unsigned long)[data_entries count]);

        [data_entries enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            DBDataEntry *dataEntry = [NSEntityDescription
                              insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DBDataEntry"
                              inManagedObjectContext:context];

            dataEntry.data_entry_id       = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[obj objectForKey:@"data_entry_id"] integerValue]];
            dataEntry.data_entry_keywords = [obj objectForKey:@"data_entry_keywords"];
            dataEntry.data_entry_name     = [obj objectForKey:@"data_entry_name"];

            NSError *error;
            if (![context save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }];

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DBDataEntry"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        NSError *error;
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        for( DBDataEntry *dataEntry in fetchedObjects ) {
            //NSLog(@"data_entry_id: %@", dataEntry.data_entry_id);
            //NSLog(@"data_entry_keywords: %@", dataEntry.data_entry_keywords);
            //NSLog(@"data_entry_name: %@", dataEntry.data_entry_name);
            NSLog(@"data_entry_id: %@ name: %@", dataEntry.data_entry_id, dataEntry.data_entry_name);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: How do you get the file open in Base.app? Run the app on the simulator, then open the file directly? Or are you copying it first? Something else maybe?

Comment: I first run Loader.App, then go to Loader.App's "Products" folder (i.e. <Path to App Folder>/Build/Products/Debug/), then open the file "MyAppDB.sqlite" with Base (or any other SQLite reader). The SQLite file does not seem to load in my Display.App if I don't VACUUM it (i.e. I can't just open then close the file to make it start working).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely reason is that you're copying the SQLite file itself but not its journal files. On iOS 7 Core Data normally uses SQLite in WAL (write-ahead logging) mode. That means that besides `MyAppDB.sqlite` there will be files named `MyAppDB.sqlite-wal` and `MyAppDB.sqlite-shm`. Those files are crucial. If you copy just the SQLite file but not the journals, you'll lose data (as you've seen).

When you open the SQLite file in Base.app and vacuum, all the changes in the journal files are rolled into the main SQLite file itself. You're doing an extra step that eliminates the need to copy the journal files.

You have a couple of different options:

- The easy way is to just copy all of the files. Problem solved.
- Another option is to change the journal mode in your loader app to avoid the need to copy more files. You'd do this by passing an extra option when adding the persistent store:

  ```
  NSDictionary *options = @{ NSSQLitePragmasOption :  @{ @"journal_mode": @"DELETE" } };
  ```

Use that when calling `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:`.

Comment: For several reasons that are too long to discuss in a comment, I would **strongly** recommend going with option 2.

Comment: Uh oh, have to watch my answers when Marcus is around. Maybe these reasons would fit into a blog post?

Comment: Yes they will once we are done with our research and radar filings :)

Comment: Fantastic! That was exactly what my problem was. Thank you very much! :) I did decide to go with option 2 as more files becomes more hassle. I assume there are also security risks with the journals? SQLite is still, mostly, a black box to me. I will have to look into this WAL mode.