# Reading pre-populated Sqlite.db in ios7

Tags: database, sqlite, core-data, ios7

I'm really new to ios world and I've got an app that was rejected by Apple because it takes to long to load data from an api (lots of records to save to my database). So I've decided to deliver my app with a prepopulated sqlite database to prevent from the initial load of objects.

First of all I've checked this site to understand how to insert my database in my project.
[Site](http://wiki.gxtechnical.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?HowTo%3a%20Create%20offline%20SD%20applications%20with%20preloaded%20database,#Article)

I don't think the site is updated because in the ios7 the database created comes with 3 different files in the cache folder

- database
- database-wal
- database-shm

Which one should I use to import?
And second of all how should I read the database file and copy/create my database from there?
My current database is created using CoreData, will that be a problem when i try to copy/create the imported database?

Tutorials and code snippets are welcome :)

Comment: It's not exactly a duplicate, but my answer here covers why those files are different and what you should do in this situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687547/nsmanagedobjectcontext-not-saving-properly-to-sqlite/20692638#20692638

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few researches and tests I managed to do it.

So I added the sqlite database to the project, according to the link in my question.
I've found this useful post that almost did the job. [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982541/preloading-a-database-in-ios-7)

So I've modified the persistentStoreCoordinator method on AppDelegate adding this code
and the database requests that I had with the old database worked with no problem.

```
NSDictionary *options = @{ NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"} };

if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDB.sqlite"];

NSError *error = nil;
_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]])
{
    NSURL *preloadURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyDB" ofType:@"sqlite"]];
    NSError* err = nil;

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:preloadURL toURL:storeURL error:&err])
    {
        NSLog (@"Error - Could not preload database.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to remember is that you really should create this pre-populated database using Core Data.

To avoid having three files, the tool that creates the database needs to close it correctly. Here’s what [SQLite website](http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html) for more info.

I don’t know if Core Data does this if you properly tear down Core Data stack, but it probably should. If it won’t do this, try to open and close the database that Core Data created using sqlite utility.

How you should use it in the app depends on your app. If this is some initial state from which the user is supposed to continue populating the database, you could just copy the file to the appropriate place (like Application Data subfolder) before initializing Core Data stack.

Another case is when this database is an example database like a photo library with photos that user is not supposed to keep when she starts using the app. In this case I would recommend separate this database and the user’s database.

The third case is when this database is kind of a big catalog of something. And the user adds additional entries to it. You’ll probably want to update this catalog from time to time without touching user’s entries. In this case I would also recommend not to mix user’s data with this catalog.